How to pass additional data to the ViewModel from a Jetpack Compose screen?
I'm navigating to a destination that initially displays a DatePickerModal, and a set of buttons on the screen. When the user selects a date and clicks on one of the buttons, I want to pass the selected date and the button that was pressed to the ViewModel, so that based on that data, actions can be executed in the data repository.
My problem is that I don't know how to pass both data at the same time.
These are the relevant parts of my code:
CalendarScreen
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Composable
internal fun CalendarScreen(
    viewModel: CalendarViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val selectedTopicId by viewModel.selectedTopicIdd.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    var showModal by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    ButtonsScreenCalendar(
        onTopicButtonClicked = viewModel::onTopicClick,
        onDateSelected = viewModel::onDateSelected
    )
    var selectedDate by remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(null) }
    if (selectedDate != null) {
        val date = Date(selectedDate!!)
        val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
        Text("Selected date: $formattedDate")
    } else {
        Text("No date selected")
    }

    if (showModal) {
        DatePickerModal(
            onDateSelected = {
                selectedDate = it
                viewModel::onDateSelected
                showModal = false
            },
            onDismiss = { showModal = false }
        )
    }
}

ButtonsScreenCalendar
@ExperimentalLayoutApi
@Composable
fun ButtonsScreenCalendar(
    onTopicButtonClicked: (String) -> Unit,
    onDateSelected: (Long)-> Unit
) {
    /* Some code */
    FlowRow(modifier = rowModifier) {
        it.items.forEach {
            HomeButton(it) {
                onTopicButtonClicked(it.id.toString())
                onDateSelected
            }
            Spacer(modifier = chipModifier)
        }
    }
}

HomeButton
@Composable
fun HomeButton(
    itemUI: ItemUI,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    AssistChip(
        onClick = { onClick() },
        label = { Text(itemUI.title) }
    )
}

CalendarViewModel
@HiltViewModel
class CalendarViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val universalisRepository: UniversalisRepository,
    getTopicWithDate: GetTopicWithDateUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val selectedTopicIdKey = "selectedTopicIdKey"
    private val selectedTopicId = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(
        key = selectedTopicIdKey,
        initialValue = 1, //TODO
    )

    //TODO Invoque use case passing topic and date

    /* Some code */

    
    fun onTopicClick(topicId: String?) {
        savedStateHandle[TOPIC_ID_ARG] = topicId
    }
}

In the onTopicClick method of the CalendarViewModel I can see the button that was pressed, but I don't know how to get the date as well.

"I don't know how to get the date as well" -- your viewmodel already has a onDateSelected() function. Right now, though, you are only referencing it, not calling it. Have you tried calling it to pass the date to the viewmodel when the date is selected?

@CommonsWare You are right. I wasn't calling onDateSelected. Changing it to viewModel.onDateSelected(selectedDate) works. Thanks!

By executing viewModel::onDateSelected, you are obtaining a callable method reference. The problem is however that you are doing nothing with that callable method reference. Your IDE should actually be complaining about that:

The expression is unused

So to execute the function that you were getting a reference to, you would need to first store the obtained reference somewhere and then explicitly invoke it:
val myViewModelFunctionReference = viewModel::onDateSelected
myViewModelFunctionReference.invoke(it)

This however is doing exactly the same as simply calling
viewModel.onDateSelected(it)

But in which situation could you use a function reference?
You can use a function reference when you need to provide a function as a parameter. Please have a look at the following example:
@Composable
fun DemoComposable() {

    val viewModel = MyViewModel()

    Button(
        onClick = {
            val myViewModelFunction = viewModel::printLog
            printLog.invoke()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "LOG")
    }
}

class MyViewModel {
    fun printLog() {
        Log.d("TEST", "SUCCESSFUL")
    }
}

As we mentioned earlier, we can simplify this to
@Composable
fun DemoComposable() {

    val viewModel = MyViewModel()

    Button(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.printLog()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "LOG")
    }
}

Now, we see that actually, we are doing nothing except directly invoking another function in the onClick lamdba. As both the onClick and the printLog function have the same function signature of () -> Unit, we can directly pass a function reference as the onClick parameter and get rid of the unnecessary lamdba:
@Composable
fun DemoComposable() {

    val viewModel = MyViewModel()

    Button(
        onClick = viewModel::printLog
    ) {
        Text(text = "LOG")
    }
}
                

